# JMock assertIsSatisfied in TearDown?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmock

I don't know why, but I have always written my JMock tests like this:

```
@Test
public void testMyThing() throws Exception {
    mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{
        oneOf(mockObj).foo();
    }});
    testObj.bar(); // calls mockObj.foo()
    mockery.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

But when there are many tests, is it better to move `assertIsSatisfied` to the tear-down?

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mockery.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to use the JMock runner. Annotate the class with

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class TestClass {
```

This will call the assertion at the right place in the test lifecycle. Teardown isn't the right place as a failure might not be reported in correctly and might mess up other cleanup.

We also have a mockery rule in the repository that works with the new @Rule infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tend to do it in teardown.  It keeps the focus of the individual test methods on what they're actually testing, by removing the boilerplate out into the `@After`- it's critical to me that tests are as expressive and readable as possible.

In fact, I sometimes take it further than that, and use a `JMockSupport` base class that handles the `Mockery` for me (as well as providing convenience implementations of `mock(...)`). This is just a convenience, of course, and by no means a requirement like it was in JUnit 3.

Comment: Please consider using the runner or the new rule implementation. If you use @After, the exception will not be thrown at the right time in the test lifecycle.